# How I can identify this font?

Tags: font-identification

I browsed dafont.com for hours and used sites where you upload your image and it tells you what fonts are similar but I found nothing alike.

There are similar fonts (Bebas Neue, Headline) but the capital E is different.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not everything is a font you can download. In many instances specific letters of a pre-existing font may be edited in a vector image editor, to customise them.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks! You are right. But this font was used for article headers in a magazine for multiple issues. So I am pretty sure it was a font. Perhaps it was a custom-made. But maybe, luckily, not.

Comment: Yes, if wasn't a one-off, then it could even be a custom font that started off as a regular font. It is certainly possible to edit fonts, if the license allows that.

Comment: 90s *maybe* [House Industries](https://houseind.com/fonts). They did a lot of those "broken" or "trendy" fonts at the time.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, I'll check it ouy

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the "upload to identify" sites, you have a few other options...

If you can find the font used anywhere online, you could use the WhatFont browser extension to easily identify it (for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en)/[Safari](http://www.chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html)/[Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zjm-whatfont/)).

If you can find the font in a PDF file, open the PDF in a viewer, then try File > Properties > Fonts to see a list of all embedded fonts.